# Iron Golems not spawning - MC Bedrock

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

This is really frustrating, especially considering that it worked before. I am trying to make an iron farm in survival mode (MCPE - Bedrock), but no Iron Golems are spawning once I moved the villagers into position. I am on the newest version of MC (1.18.12)

**Images and info:**
*Entire Build:*
[image]
*Right Side:*
[image]
*Left Side:*
[image]

|  | Left Side | Right Side |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Work Stations | 20 | 10 |
| Beds | 20 | 24 |
| Villagers | 13 adults, 2 nitwits, 1 child | 14 adults, 3 children |

**The annoying part:**

The annoying part is that when I was breeding the villagers on the ground (20-22 villagers, no children, 20-30 beds, ~10 workstations) Iron Golems were spawning just fine. As soon as I moved the villagers to their current position, they stopped spawning. What is going on? Thanks for any assistance!

EDIT:

So I moved a villager to the center of the farm (Above the lava) with a bed and workstation. 3 Iron Golems spawned (But not inside the farm, they spawned on the ground around the farm), then nothing else. I think it happened when the villager I moved un-linked from his bed, but I could not get him linked to his new bed (He kept linking to other beds, even after being completely enclosed in dirt and cobblestone. Is there something specific I should do to fix this (hopefully) permanently? Thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer with new information based on your edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Fandom page explanation](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Iron_golem_farming#Village_center)

Short answer: Iron golems attempt to spawn at the "village center", but due to the current setup there isn't room for the golem at this point.

---

> A village center is the northwest bottom corner of a point-of-interest (POI) block, which can be a bed pillow, bell, or workstation. The village center always begins as the pillow of the first bed linked to a villager. It can shift when a villager links to a new POI or unlinks from a POI after three failed attempts to pathfind to it, or after removal of either the villager or the POI from the village. The game attempts to make the village center correspond roughly to the geometric center of all linked POI in a village, but there is randomness involved and shifts can seem erratic.

> To search for a spawnable spot during a spawn attempt, the game checks 10 random X, Y, Z coordinates in the 16×6×16 volume around the village center. The spawn attempt succeeds if a chosen coordinate meets the following conditions:
>
> - **There is a solid block underneath.**
> - The 2×4×2 volume extending -1 X (west), +3 Y (upward), and -1 Z (north) from the chosen coordinate does not contain any solid or full blocks.

It appears that (based on your screenshot) there isn't an area for the golems to spawn around the village center (whatever it is right now).

---

## Update based on edit in question

To prevent iron golems from spawning on the ground, place a slab (NOT upside-down) on every block you don't want the golems to spawn on (within the 16x6x16 spawn area). This is often used in mob farms to prevent mobs spawning outside the collection chamber.

Comment: Ah. That makes sense. So if I placed a villager, bed, and workstation above the water, would that move the village center to above the water? As long as the bed and workstation were less than 16 blocks away from the solid block under the water, it would work, right? Thanks for the help!